# vue - cannot convert submitEvent.target to formdata

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

### update

I made a **correct** function based on the answer below

```
export function submitEvent_2_json(e) {
    const jsondata = {}
    let fd= new FormData(e.target)
    for (let key of fd.entries()) {
        jsondata[key[0]]=key[1]
    }
    return jsondata
}
```

#### origional problem

I'm trying to get data from form and convert it to json
It's obvious that data is in `submitEvent.target`(as follow picture), but the result is `undefined` or `null`

```
<template>
<form @submit.prevent="submit">
  <input id="aa"/>
  <button type="submit">ok</button>
</form>
</template>

<script setup>
function submit(e) {
  console.log(e)
  let fd= new FormData(e.target)
  console.log(fd)
  console.log(e.formData)
  console.log(fd.entries())
}
</script>
```

output
[image: submitevent]
[image: output]

Comment: `e.target` will refer to the form why you want add the `form` element on `FormData`?, Please describe what you are looking for?

Comment: ```new FormData(e.target)``` return```{}```instead of error, so i don't think that there is a grammer mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's how `FormData` works

> FormData is a special type of object which is not stringifyable can cannot just be printed out using console.log

If you want to get an item inside, you can use `get` method.

EX:

```
fd.get('username');
```

If you want get all entries inside, you can loop through

```
for (var key of fd.entries()) {
  console.log(key[0] + ', ' + key[1])
}
```